# How to handle the issue of using different versions of shared libraries (so) in an application?

Tags: android, shared-libraries

My application includes SDK A and SDK B, both of which depend on libgnustl_shared.so. However, they depend on different versions of libgnustl_shared.so. If the application loads the version required by SDK A, SDK B will encounter the following error at runtime:

```
    2024-01-22 16:18:45.786 17159-17159 MainActivity   D  initAkuvoxSDK
    2024-01-22 16:18:45.804 17159-17159 Akuvox         E  null: initAKTalkSDK(6): initAKTalkSDK
    2024-01-22 16:18:45.833 17159-17159 MainActivity   D  initSDK faild:dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "vpx_codec_destroy" referenced by "/data/app/~~oEVKSXHX5pZYt2cfbKQxUA==/com.lifesmart.nature.feature.imou.app-W4ytQs2rHgy2kvJJ4im0qw==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a/libmediaengine.so"...
```

Similarly, if the application loads the version required by SDK B, SDK A will encounter the following error at runtime:

```
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.047 19126-19126 System.err W  java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: cannot locate symbol "_ZNSsD1Ev" referenced by "/data/app/~~bAS2agkoBsPcKUDA9pUdcg==/com.lifesmart.nature.feature.imou.app-Rf3ByH7-rhJyJFcP7_velw==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a/libLechangeSDK.so"...
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.048 19126-19126 System.err W    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1087)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.048 19126-19126 System.err W    at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:1008)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.048 19126-19126 System.err W    at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1664)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.048 19126-19126 System.err W    at com.lechange.opensdk.a.<clinit>(Loader.java:18)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.048 19126-19126 System.err W    at com.lechange.opensdk.a.a(Loader.java:35)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.048 19126-19126 System.err W    at com.lechange.opensdk.api.LCOpenSDK_Api_Impl$SingletonHolder.<clinit>(LCOpenSDK_Api_Impl.java:58)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.049 19126-19126 System.err W    at com.lechange.opensdk.api.LCOpenSDK_Api_Impl$SingletonHolder.a(LCOpenSDK_Api_Impl.java:50)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.049 19126-19126 System.err W    at com.lechange.opensdk.api.LCOpenSDK_Api_Impl.initOpenApi(LCOpenSDK_Api_Impl.java:94)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.049 19126-19126 System.err W    at com.lechange.opensdk.api.LCOpenSDK_Api.initOpenApi(LCOpenSDK_Api.java:48)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.049 19126-19126 System.err W    at com.lifesmart.nature.feature.imou.pkg.sdk.SDKWrapper.init(SDKWrapper.kt:27)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.049 19126-19126 System.err W    at com.lifesmart.nature.feature.imou.app.LeCameraDialogFragment$initData$1.invoke(LeCameraDialogFragment.kt:116)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.049 19126-19126 System.err W    at com.lifesmart.nature.feature.imou.app.LeCameraDialogFragment$initData$1.invoke(LeCameraDialogFragment.kt:114)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.050 19126-19126 System.err W    at com.lifesmart.nature.feature.imou.app.LeCameraDialogFragment.initData$lambda$2(LeCameraDialogFragment.kt:114)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.050 19126-19126 System.err W    at com.lifesmart.nature.feature.imou.app.LeCameraDialogFragment.$r8$lambda$nctCiCHEf4Q0fUDv8wF2ZEwZznY(Unknown Source:0)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.050 19126-19126 System.err W    at com.lifesmart.nature.feature.imou.app.LeCameraDialogFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onChanged(Unknown Source:2)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.050 19126-19126 System.err W    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:131)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.050 19126-19126 System.err W    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:149)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.050 19126-19126 System.err W    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.setValue(LiveData.java:307)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.051 19126-19126 System.err W    at androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData.setValue(MutableLiveData.java:50)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.051 19126-19126 System.err W    at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$1.run(LiveData.java:91)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.051 19126-19126 System.err W    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.051 19126-19126 System.err W    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.052 19126-19126 System.err W    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.052 19126-19126 System.err W    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7660)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.052 19126-19126 System.err W    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.052 19126-19126 System.err W    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592)
    2024-01-22 17:23:16.052 19126-19126 System.err W    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:947)
```

How can I handle this issue and make both SDKs work properly? Here is some information that may help in resolving the problem:
My Application：
minSdk 21
targetSdk 29
compileSdk 33

By running the command `nm -D libgnustl_shared.so`, I found that both `vpx_codec_destroy` and `_ZNSsD1Ev` mentioned in the error messages above are symbols from `libgnustl_shared.so`, but they belong to different versions of `libgnustl_shared.so`.

```
nm -D /Users/hanwen/temp/so_conflict/libgnustl_shared_SDK_A.so | grep _ZNSsD1Ev
        0008adac W _ZNSsD1Ev
nm -D /Users/hanwen/temp/so_conflict/libgnustl_shared_SDK_A.so | grep vpx_codec_destroy
# no output

nm -D /Users/hanwen/temp/so_conflict/libgnustl_shared_SDK_B.so | grep _ZNSsD1Ev
# no output
nm -D /Users/hanwen/temp/so_conflict/libgnustl_shared_SDK_B.so | grep vpx_codec_destroy
    0005e92c T vpx_codec_destroy
```

Currently, my solution is to use multiple processes, allowing each SDK to load its own version of the shared library in its own process. However, this approach increases the overall memory usage.

Any suggestions you have will be helpful to me :)

Comment: You should show the _exact_ and _complete_ error message, not an approximation thereof. Also the exact output from `nm -D ... | grep vpx_codec_destroy` .

Comment: @EmployedRussian Thank you very much for your suggestions! I have added these details.

Comment: `(null)` is a) not something `nm -D` should ever print and b) doesn't match your `grep`. Maybe you mean that `grep` produced _no output_ ? In that case, use a comment like `# no output`.

Comment: @EmployedRussian Thank you for pointing out my mistakes! :) I've modified it.